# AMCharts Show bar on zero value

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is it possible to make a "fake" stacked bar graph where the 0 value is pushed i.e. 10px up, so 0 values will have a 10px bar, so the users always have something to click on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a property that allows you to do this, however you have a few of workarounds.

You can make your chart 3D by setting the [`angle`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#angle) and [`depth3D`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#depth3D) properties. This gives zero-sized bars more surface area to click on at the axis level. This doesn't work too well with stacked charts, though.

Alternatively, you can add an invisible bullet to your columns. You can specify a [`bullet`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bullet) shape in your graph and then set the [`bulletAlpha`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bulletAlpha) to 0 so that they're invisible, but still clickable. You can also increase the size by setting [`bulletSize`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bulletSize) to a larger number, which increases the hitbox:

```
  "graphs": [{
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 20, //used to increase the hitbox
    "bulletAlpha": 0,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  },
  // ...
  ]
```

I created a demo with invisible bullets and visible bullets to illustrate the hitbox and location [here](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/091899ed00c3b63c9992389520229301). I set the `bulletSize` to 20 to make it large enough to cover some of the area where the balloon appears so the user can click a round there

As a final alternative, you can create an invisible, non-clustered graph that points to a valueField that corresponds to the largest value from your data. This invisible column will encompass the space above each category up to the value in the valueField, so any the empty space above the columns will trigger a click event as well.

```
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "max": 665
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 0,
    "max": 665
  },
  // ...
  ],
  "graphs": [{
    // invisible graph - set clustered to false and all other visible properties and interactive properties to 0 or false
    "clustered": false,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "max"
  }, {
    // real graph
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
```

Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/1533d0ce4ab4e2fb08148cfd9e308d15?editors=0010) of this method.

Comment: Thanks, you're right that that it does not exactly give the result wanted, however the business (and designers) accepted that it was not possible and settled with a bullet (with color)